# Using geometry in PL\pgSQL functions?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, plpgsql

I am trying to create a function in PL\pgSQL procedural language of two geometric data types, multipoint and multiline string for example. I want to select all lines within 30 meter distance for all points. Here is what I have tried:

```
Create OR Replace Function get_streets(bar.geom geometry foo.geom geometry)
Returns geometry AS $$
BEGIN
  IF ST_DWithin(bar.geom, foo.geom, 30.0) Then
    Return foo.geom;
  ELSE
    Return null;
  END IF
  Return foo.geom;
END;
$$ Language plpgsql;
```

The function returns an error because of geometry data type. Any advice for using/handling geometry data in plpgsql functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have quite a few small syntax mistakes in your function. See the version below for a working function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_streets(g1 geometry, g2 geometry) RETURNS geometry AS $$
BEGIN
  IF ST_DWithin(g1, g2, 30.0) THEN
    RETURN g2;
  END IF;
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Most importantly: do not use `table.field` notation for the parameters. Instead, use a simple name and use the appropriate field when you call the function:

```
SELECT get_streets(bar.geom, foo.geom)
FROM bar
JOIN foo on ...
```

Incidentally, you can get the same functionality without using a function at all:

```
SELECT foo.geom
FROM foo
JOIN bar ON ST_DWithin(bar.geom, foo.geom, 30)
WHERE <other conditions>;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I corrected the syntax as per your suggestion and it worked! Yes, I am aware of an alternate approach for direct query. Nevertheless, I was more interested to do it according to "plpgsql" way. Thanks for the alternate approach as well.